# Alternative between parser rule and lexer rule

Tags: antlr

The question is buried in the update section of another question, now specifically ask it.

I am using antlr3.4.

I have a simple grammar trying to parse 2 types of text, the line started with "#include" and others. Here is my grammar:

```
cmds
    : cmd+
    ;

cmd
    : include_cmd |  other_cmd
    ;

include_cmd
    : INCLUDE  DOUBLE_QUOTE  FILE_NAME  DOUBLE_QUOTE
    ;

other_cmd
    : (~INCLUDE)+
    ;


INCLUDE
    : '#include'
    ;

DOUBLE_QUOTE
    : '"'
    ;

FILE_NAME
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')+
    ;

New_Line 
    : ('\r' | '\n')+   
    ;

WS 
    : ('\t' | ' ')+  {$channel = HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

But I get such warning:

```
Decision can match input such as "{DOUBLE_QUOTE..FILE_NAME, New_Line..WS}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

I guess this is because a double quote can match both other_cmd rule and DOUBLE_QUOTE rule, but I am wondering here, one is parser rule and the other is lexer rule, does this warning make sense?

Any help to clear this warning?

A side question - the warning message just says alternative 1,2, but it is not immediately clear to me what is 1 and what is 2, is there a way to render antlr to give more direct alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

> I guess this is because a double quote can match both other_cmd rule and DOUBLE_QUOTE rule, ...

No, that is not the issue, since `include_cmd` starts with something that `other_cmd` cannot match.

> Decision can match input such as "{DOUBLE_QUOTE..FILE_NAME, New_Line..WS}" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

The warning means that input like `foo"` (a `FILE_NAME` followed by a `DOUBLE_QUOTE`) can be matched by the parser in more than one way:

### 1. greedy

[image]

### 2. ungreedy

[image]

ANTLR will choose the greedy parse, but since an ungreedy is possible, a warning is generated. If you explicitly tell the parser to match greedily, the warning would not be issued anymore:

```
other_cmd
 : (options {greedy=true;} : ~INCLUDE)+
 ;
```

> A side question - the warning message just says alternative 1,2, but it is not immediately clear to me what is 1 and what is 2, is there a way to render antlr to give more direct alternatives?

No, not as far as I know. This warning is indeed rather cryptic. Alternatives usually denote the branches the parser can follow:

```
parser_rule
 : alternative_1 
 | alternative_2
 | alternative_3
 ;
```

But in your case, it seems ANTLR is talking about token ranges being the alternatives: `DOUBLE_QUOTE..FILE_NAME` being an alternative and `New_Line..WS` being the 2nd.