# multi alternative and rule of thumb of grammar granularity

Tags: antlr

I asked related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669870/how-to-use-similar-lexers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657396/alternative-between-parser-rule-and-lexer-rule), now I have a new question, but really I am asking for some general rule of thinking.

Here is the grammar:

```
grammar post2;


post2: action_cmd+
        ;

action_cmd
    : cmd_name  action_cmd_def  
    ;

action_cmd_def
    : (cmd_chars | cmd_literal)+   Semi_colon  
    ;

cmd_name
    : 'a'..'z'  ('a'..'z' | '0'..'9' | '_'  )*
    ;

cmd_chars
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' | '.' | ':' | '-' |'\\')
    ;

cmd_literal
    : SINGLE_QUOTE  ~(SINGLE_QUOTE | '\n' | '\r')  SINGLE_QUOTE
    ;

SINGLE_QUOTE
    : '\''
    ;

Semi_colon
    : ';'
    ;

WS : ('\t' | ' ')+  {$channel = HIDDEN;};

New_Line : ('\r' | '\n')+   {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

It is not a surprise I got this error -

```
warning(200): post2.g:16:45: 
Decision can match input such as "'_'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2

As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

The error is about rule "cmd_name".

I believe the reason is, as Bart indicated in another thread, when there is such input as "abc__", it can be parsed as either "abc_"(cmd_name) and "_"(action_cmd_def/cmd_chars) or "abc__"(cmd_name).

Here are my questions:
1) How to fix it? I tried adding "options {greedy=true;}" in front of cmd_name, but the error persists.

2) I know if I combine cmd_name and action_cmd_def into one, then the problem will be gone, this leads to the question of grammar granularity. Since ANTLR has such a powerful lexer/parser function, I really like to use the grammar to filter out meaningful string out, in this case, I know the input data for "action_cmd" must start with a command name string and then follow some messy stuff, so I like the grammar to do separate the 2 parts; otherwise I will have to write in action part using the target language (C in my case), but going deeper granularity brings so much trouble, I am in doubt if I am at a wrong track.

With this, I like to ask, what is your rule of thumb as of the grammar granularity? Am I going nuts in using grammar?

Answer (score -1):

This is a genuine ambiguity, but the greedy option should work for you.  Maybe it needs to be at the subrule level?  See if this works:

```
cmd_name
    : 'a'..'z' (options {greedy=true;} : 'a'..'z' | '0'..'9' | '_'  )*
```

As for the second part of your question, I think your rule granularity is fine.  You can also resort to using syntactic predicates if there is an ambiguity that needs more than just the greedy flag to solve.  It is well documented in the ANTLR 3 book, but not so well on the website.

It amounts to trying to match the predicate syntactically.  If it succeeds then it matches it for real, if it fails then it uses the other alternatives.  For instance, in C you don't know if you have a function declaration or definition until you see the end of the declaration, which has no lower limit on its length.  So you use a syntactic predicate to say "let's see if it is a declaration, if it is, then match it for real, if not then try the other alternatives.

```
externalDef
    :       ( "typedef" | declaration )=> declaration
    |       functionDef
    |       asm_expr
    ;
```

Comment: Hey down voter!  Speak up!  I'd like the feedback so I can improve my answer.